# How to set the Scrollbar according to the inner control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, scrollbar, wpf-4.0

I am having a user control which is to be hooked into main window at run time. So, this user control gets some width and height in the main window.

Now, this user control is having an expander control and on the click of expander some other sub user control is shown to the user and these sub user controls would be of different width and height.

So, like when a small sub user control is to be shown on the click of the expander, then control would be shown in correct manner but if the sub user control's size is large then the main user controls width or height, then we have to scroll down to see the full view of the sub user control.

**Now what I want that if sub controls size is more than user controls size, then by default full view should be shown, so as I have to set the scroll bar on the click of expander.
So, How I would set the scrollbar vertically according the size of sub user control in the XAML part**

Comment: avoid all-caps title for your questions

Comment: I really don't understand this question. Consider making an image to illustrate what you're trying to do

Comment: Hi, let WPF do this for you. Inside your sub user control place an ScrollViewer and then inside the ScrollViewer add content on runtime.